# For loop to download files once and verify them on each invocation

Tags: linux, sh

The complete script works as expected. I am able to download and verify the files. If the file is all ready present verification is retested and downloads if necessary.

I'm in the process of teaching myself bash/sh scripting. Is there a cleaner way I can implement the following section of sh script?

The files reside at different URLS. Download is a simple wget cmd and verify compares the checksum of the local file against what is expected.

```
   for f in $(cat wget-list)
   do
    # Get name file of file to download
    bn=$(basename $f)
    # If file not present attempt to download
    if [ ! -f $bn ]
    then
        download
        if verifyfile
        then
            log INFO "Download of $bn successful"
        else
            download
            if ! verifyfile
            then
                exit
            else
                log INFO "Redownload successful"
            fi
        fi
    else
        if ! verifyfile 
        then
            download
            if verifyfile
            then
                log INFO "Redownload of $bn successful"
            else
                download
                if ! verifyfile
                then
                    exit
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
   done;
```

Comment: "Works as expected" is good (actually, required), but you haven't told us what the expected behaviour is!  And it's hard to infer, given that you've not told us anything about the file called `wget-list`.  Instead of describing `download` and `verify`, please include them in the review.  I'm concerned you appear to be using global variables to communicate between functions.  Also, is this part of a function?  Or a full script?  I'd need to see a lot more of the context to be able to review this properly.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have posted a new question [[https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285297/shell-script-to-download-multiple-files-from-different-urls-using-for-loop-to-d]] incorporating your feedback with my current version of the script.